# Require a Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I Required a Regex for the below input string:

Input data - ANALYSE/xxxxxxxx:

In the string xxxxxx is any characters. Need a regex accordingly to figure it out

At the end the colon is there but i need to replace entire 'ANALYSE/xxxxxxxx:' with String.empty.

I want to replace the above string with String.empty

The regex which i used 'ANALYSE/.*' is not getting.

Provide me a regex.

Comment: Especially when asking so nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your own using this site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 4):

Do you *really* need a regex? Can't you just use

```
if (text.StartsWith("ANALYSE/"))
```

?

If you *do* definitely need a regex, just

```
ANALYSE/.*
```

will match appropriately. The removal side will depend on *exactly* what you want to do - if you could give a concrete example, that would make life easier.

Comment: The regex will match "ANALYSE/" as well. If there must be at least one 'x' use + instead of *.

Comment: I agree. It wasn't meant as a correction. Just additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ANALYSE/.*?:`

Comment: You are definitely right. You should explain though, and at least show it as `ANALYSE/.*?:` - at first glance it seems like an error. I almost added a similar answer (with `[^:]*`)